# As a prove and $f$ a differentiable function of two variables

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

> As a prove and $f$ a differentiable function of two variables $u$ and $v$ and $u = x-y$ and $v = y-x$, then $z = f (x-y, y-x)$ satisfies the equation $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$$

I thought of using the chain rule and my teacher said it would work well, but could not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ a differentiable function of two variables $u$ and $v$ and $u = x-y$ and $v = y-x$.

Suppose $z = f (x-y, y-x)$ then to show that the equation satisfies $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$$.

Hint :

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}. \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}. \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Work similarly for $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$.